# How to configure a shared volume between containers

Tags: docker

One container contains a test suite, and one container contains a webdriver. When the webdriver downloads something (yes, I have to do this, other things are checked for ContentType using a HttpURLConnection), I'd like the test suite to be able to check if that downloaded file exists.

The test suite checks in the projet's downloads subdirectory, and the webdriver has been given a download path of `/home/seluser`.

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  suite:
    build: .
    command: >
      mvn
      -Dbrowser=chrome_headless_remote
      -Dbrowser_url=http://chrome:4444/wd/hub
      -Dcucumber.filter.tags="${TAGS}"
      test
    volumes:
      - shared:${PWD}/downloads
    depends_on:
      - chrome

  chrome:
    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium:4.0.0-beta-1-20210215
    container_name: chromium-m1
    shm_size: 2gb
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - shared:/home/seluser/

volumes:
  shared:
```

```json
❯ docker volume inspect drt_shared
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-09-08T12:15:26Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "drt",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.0.0",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "shared"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/drt_shared/_data",
        "Name": "drt_shared",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

In `suite`, the directory is an existing directory copied into the image. It searches for the file in `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/downloads"`. In `chrome`, I've selected the home directory of the user selected when I log into the container.

If I use bind mounts to point to the host fs, it works as expected, but if I interpreted the Docker documentation correctly, it seems it should be possible to have that shared directory handled by docker compose.

I'm not sure how I can exactly find the problem with this. I see from the console that the downloaded file is in fact present in `/home/seluser` in `chrome`, so why can't the test suite see it? How do I start to diagnose this? Is what I want at all possible?

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is by creating endpoints that serve/expose the files

Comment: I'm guessing `${PWD}/downloads` will be expanded using the host's `$PWD` environment variable (possibly empty or possibly in your host home directory) before being interpreted as a container-side path.  Does using an absolute container path, without environment-variable references, work any better?

Comment: @DavidMaze Tried it, it doesn't. It's a git branch, copied straight into the container. I'm still hoping corneliu is wrong. :)

Comment: FWIW another solution is to have a separate db container and have all of the shared files in the db.

Comment: @corneliu It's for only one text file at a time, though.

Comment: how about installing samba server in the container and sharing that folder through samba and then mounting the shared folder in the container that needs access to it?

Comment: @corneliu I'm going to see if we can use Compose v2 for the project. This looks interesting: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes_from

Comment: @corneliu I figured it out with v3. Will post code later, dinner time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  suite:
    build: .
    command: >
      mvn
      -Dbrowser=chrome_headless_remote
      -Dbrowser_url=http://chrome:4444/wd/hub
      -Dcucumber.filter.tags="${TAGS}"
      test
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: shared
        target: /downloads
    depends_on:
      - chrome

  chrome:
    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium:4.0.0-beta-1-20210215
    container_name: chromium-m1
    shm_size: 2gb
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: shared
        target: /home/seluser

volumes:
  shared:
```

I think this is what's happening (someone please confirm or correct):

`suite:volumes`
When creating an image from a directory, that directory goes into the root of the container. So `/downloads` is from that root in that container. The test suite checks this location.

`chrome:volumes`
The webdriver is told to save the file in this location. It's just the home directory.

So in our test suite, the webdriver is told to save files in the home directory of that container's user (`/home/seluser`). The test suite then checks for files in its own `/downloads` directory.